# How to make a QTextEdit look disabled

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit

At some point, I need to make a `QTextEdit` look like it was disabled.

I'm not against calling `setEnabled(false)`, but then the `QTextEdit` does not receive `QContextMenuEvent` event anymore (and I need a right-click context menu to be available....because that's how the `QTextEdit` gets disabled by the user, so that's how I want him to enable it back).

So I do:

```
QColor mainWindowBgColor = palette().color(QPalette::Window);
// for the current widget
setStyleSheet(QString("background-color: %0").arg(mainWindowBgColor.name(QColor::HexRgb)));
```

This looks good, unless you right-click the widget and show it's context menu: The context menu appears but looks bad. Item highlighting does not work and then selected text is hardly visible (painted in white on a grey background).

How could I either:

- call `setEnabled(false)` and have right-mouse click context menu be accessible
- or use `setStyleSheet` but make sure it won't be usd by the context menu widget begin painted
- or any alternative....

Comment: [`readOnly`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#readOnly-prop)?

Comment: Why can't you apply the style sheet on the QTextEdit only?

Comment: @king_nak: That's what I do, but apparently it gets inherited by the context menu

Comment: Oh, I see. Check my answer below...

Comment: @DmitrySazonov: `setReadOnly( true )` does not make the widget look disabled (backgroun dis still white, while expected to be grey)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Style sheets are inherited by all sub-widgets. To make a style sheet apply only to a certain widget (or a type of widgets), you have to specify accessors.

E.g.

```
setStyleSheet(QString(
    "QTextEdit { background-color: %0 }"
    ).arg(mainWindowBgColor.name(QColor::HexRgb)));
```

Comment: This is definitely the easiest way to fix my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would try subclassing `QTextEdit` and overriding `contextMenuEvent`. There I would show (exec) a standard menu, after changing its stylesheet:

```
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QContextMenuEvent>
#include <QMenu>

class TextEdit : public QTextEdit
{
public:
    TextEdit(QWidget* p) : QTextEdit(p){}
protected:
    void contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent * event)
    {
        QMenu * menu = createStandardContextMenu();
        menu->setStyleSheet("background-color: gray");
        menu->exec(QCursor::pos());
    }
};
```

In the above example I set the menu background color to gray, but the goal of this example is to show one can override the menu style sheet, so to prevent the menu to use the one inherited from its parent.

Comment: Nice. But king_nak makes it easier to fix the problem. Thanks for your help.